# Pandas: Sensor data has 3 headers. Need to retain them after gap-filling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working with sensor-data that comes off of Decagon Em50g data loggers. Before I do anything with these data they need to be gap-filled according to our study period (start and end data/time). The raw sensor data from the loggers have 3 headers that need to be retained after gap-filling (they have important metadata that gets pulled in a second script that tidy's up the data after gap-filling). I need to do this for many files and am trying to do it for one first.

My approach: I read in sensor-data in two ways, once to store the first 2 headers 'headers_for_insert' (for later insertion) and second to have the 3rd header as the main header ('with_headers') for joining/gap-filling. After this, I create a date_time series for the duration of our study trial and then join this to the 'with_headers' data-frame for gap-filling.

Then, I need to basically stack the other 2 headers back on the gap-filled data-frame so that the 3 headers are retained when I export as a csv.

I've tried so many things and would appreciate any guidance on how to come up with a solution.

Click here for an image of what I'm trying to accomplish:

image of tables and headers

[image]

image of what I need the final table to look like

[image]

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import glob

# read in data, one with headers and one without
without_headers = pd.read_excel('D1Y-05Feb2018-1331.xls',  header=None)
with_headers = pd.read_excel('D1Y-05Feb2018-1331.xls',  header=2)

# subset first two rows from 'without_headers' (these will be inserted as headers later)
headers_for_insert = without_headers.iloc[0:2,:]

# change date-time heading to 'date_time'
with_headers = with_headers.rename(columns = {'Measurement Time':'date_time'})
with_headers = with_headers.set_index('date_time')

# create variables for your start and end date/time
start='12/15/2017 00:00:00'
end='2/4/2018 12:00:00'

# create dataframe that has the date-time series for duration of study trial
date_range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H')
date_range_series = pd.Series(date_range)
date_range_df = pd.DataFrame(date_range_series)
date_range_df.columns = ['date_time']
date_range_df = date_range_df.set_index('date_time')

# Left hand join using created time-series as series to join on.
gap_filled = date_range_df.join(with_headers)
gap_filled = gap_filled.reset_index()

# stack 'headers_for_insert' on top of 'gap_filled' dataframe
'''Here I want to put the 2 headers that I stored in 'headers_for_insert' 
on top of the header in 'gap_filled' so that the output csv will have a
total of 3 headers'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who have given this question some thought.

Update:

I found a solution with the following code (opening in excel and all is good).
However, I'm getting an error when I try to read back into as a data-frame.

```
# write 'headers_for_insert' to csv as a way to start building table.
headers_for_insert.to_csv('headers.csv', index=False, header=False)

# open 'headers.csv' and append the 'gap_filled' dataframe to the 2 headers
with open('headers.csv', 'a') as f:
    gap_filled.to_csv(f, index=False, header=True, encoding='utf-8')

# the above lines of code worked (here I'm reading in the csv to test)
solved = pd.read_csv('headers.csv')
```

**However, I'm getting this error when I try to read in the csv as a dataframe:** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 1: invalid start byte